# how to use tinymce with full rtl direction

Tags: tinymce, right-to-left, tinymce-4

I want to use the new (4.x) tinymce in full rtl.

Take a look here http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xwdaab/1

I set

```
directionality: "rtl",
```

But it's only effect the input area, I want that all the toolbars will align to the right side (rtl)

How can I do this?

In the old version the was the theme "advanced" and I used

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "right",
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
I removed "fullpage" from the plugins argument and now it works for me.

I changed this code:

```
plugins: [
                "advlist directionality autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                "table contextmenu textcolor paste fullpage textcolor"
        ],
```

to this:

```
plugins: [
                "advlist directionality autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                "table contextmenu textcolor paste textcolor"
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

tinymce 4.0.7 >   auto detects toolbar alignment by language pack(rtl or ltr).

take a look at: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32748

Answer (score 0):

If you want too change plugins direction you should wrap your tiny with a container with a class
and write below css code in your codes

```
.containerClass .mce-flow-layout {
    white-space: normal;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```